# Best language for Android and Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, ide

I'm looking for opinions on the best development language to use to maintain one set of high-level application code for apps that can execute on Android and Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Android only supports Java and Kotlin. Java is also supported on on Raspberry Pi. I have seen some people talk about using Kotlin on Rasberry but I think community support will be very limited if you go with Kotlin.

Also are you sharing code between the 2 platforms?? If you are sharing code then Java seems a safer bet as of now than Kotlin but if both code bases are not sharing anything and you you can use Kotlin for Android and any other supported language like Python Java JS or C for Rasberry Pi

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to offer your thoughts.

I've decided to use Dart, along with the Webstorm IDE.  Dart is an OOP language, multiplatform (potentially platform independent), and can compile to bytecode, Javascript or host object code.  It sounds pretty exciting... we'll see after I have completed a couple of projects ;-)

https://dart.dev/overview

Answer (score 0):

As of now [Android](https://mobulous.com/android-app-development) just sustains Java as well as Kotlin. Java is likewise sustained on Raspberry Pi I have seen some individuals speak about using Kotlin on Rasberry yet I assume area support will be extremely minimal if you choose Kotlin.

Likewise are you sharing code in between the 2 systems?? If you are sharing code after that Java seems a safer wager already than Kotlin however if both code bases are not sharing anything as well as you can utilize Kotlin for Android and any other supported language like Python Java JS or C for Rasberry Pi.